# Searching name in PHP

Tags: php

How to search for a name and expected to have the results in full name and multiple name.

For example;

When you search **John**,
the results will be appeared as **John Doe**, not as **John** only and name with John Max also can be appeared.

Comment: You have names in database table?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Yes, there are names in my database table.

Comment: Assuming you're pulling them out of an array, after you've pulled the names from a database, my answer should work

Answer (score 0):

```
$search="John";
$names=["John Doe", "John Max", "Jane Doe", "Jane Max"];
foreach($names as $name)//iterates through the array
{
 if(stripos($name,$search)!=false)//stripos returns an int if its in the string, false if it isn't.
 {
  echo $name;//the entire name
 }
}
```

This code will iterate through your array of names (foreach), and find names that contain the search string, regardless of case(stripos), later echo'ing out the entire name (echo)

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE LIKE`

```
"SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 
                  name LIKE '%$name_query%' OR 
                  lastname LIKE '%$lastname_query%'";
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970218/searching-name-in-php#comment82910213_47970283

Answer (score 0):

Use a composite column in your table where you combine firstname and lastname (name it fullname) and use that one for your search.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE fullname LIKE '$name_query%'
```

Comment: Don't use % both sides it is overkill sometimes.

Comment: true, my mistake i copied the query from Goms and modified it for laziness sack :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to return every name. (PDO Statement).
Set `$shortname` with short name.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE name LIKE concat('%', :shortname, '%')");
$stmt->bindValue(':shortname', $shortname, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then you can do this to return your name.

```
$user['name'];
```